# counting unique monthly visitors to display on graph

Tags: php, mysql, date, visitors

I have a table which records visitors by IP address, date first visited and date last visited,  for multiple websites. Both dates are in datetime format like `2016-08-07 12:14:44`. Each record is specific to a website reference.

I am trying to list the last 6 months by year and month like `(Y-m)`

```
2016-08
2016-07
2016-06
```

etc...
I have managed to do this although am struggling on the code to count distinct visitors, here is what I have so far:

```
$this_month = date('Y-m');

$count = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(ip_address)) as count FROM `all_website_stats` WHERE `website_ref` = '$show_website_ref' AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_first_viewed) = '$this_month' AND `date_first_viewed` = `date_last_viewed`");
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($count);
echo $rowcount;
```

This will be performed 6 times to get the final count of visitors who have not returned. Although this code is returning errors. And when I did manage to get it working, it only counted `1` or `0` which is incorrect.

It shown the error once I added `date_first_viewed = date_last_viewed` which I guess is probably wrong. Although I need to make sure that the `date_first_visited` is the same as `date_last_visited` in the database, else the result is a returning visitor instead.

Can somebody point me in the right direction here and let me know what I'm doing wrong? I'm not great with these kind of date checks with MySQL.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you want all unique visitors per month.  However, I would describe your query as getting all one-time visitors per month.  If so, it seems like you need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_first_viewed) as yyyymm,
       COUNT(ip_address)) as count
FROM `all_website_stats` aws
WHERE `website_ref` = '$show_website_ref' AND
      `date_first_viewed` = `date_last_viewed`
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_first_viewed);
```

You can add a condition to the `WHERE` clause to specify the time period for the returned rows.

The `WHERE` clause would look something like this:

```
WHERE date_first_viewed >= '2016-01-01'
```

Comment: I have added `AND EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM date_first_viewed) = '$this_month'` to get just the results from this month below the `date_first_viewed = date_last_viewed` yet I'm not getting any results?

Comment: Without the addition, the script worked but retrieved all one-time visitors in the database rather than by a specific month.